# How can I remove the character `b` from the output?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

```
 <member>
    <detaileddescription>
        Hello
        <formula id="39">my</formula>
        name
        <formula id="102">is</formula>
        Buddy.
        <formula id="103">I</formula>
        am a
        <itemizedlist>
            <listitem>
            superhero
            <formula id="104">.</formula>
            </listitem>
            <listitem>
                At least,
                <formula id="105">I think</formula>
            </listitem>
        </itemizedlist>
        so...:)
        <simplesect kind="see">
            What
            <ref refid="ref_id" kindref="ref_kindref">do you</ref>
            <bold>think</bold> ?
        </simplesect>
        Let me know. :)
    </detaileddescription>
 </member>
```

The [following source code](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0400__XML/ExtractingTextfromXMLDocuments.htm) works:

```
from xml.parsers import expat

xmlFile = "xml.xml"


class xmlText(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.textBuff = ""

    def CharacterData(self, data):
        data = data.strip()
        if data:
            data = data.encode('ascii')
            self.textBuff += str(data) + "\n"

    def Parse(self, fName):
        xmlParser = expat.ParserCreate()
        xmlParser.CharacterDataHandler = self.CharacterData
        xmlParser.Parse(open(fName).read(), 1)


xText = xmlText()
xText.Parse(xmlFile)
print("Text from %s\n=" % xmlFile)
print(xText.textBuff)
```

**Output**

```
Text from xml.xml
=
b'Hello'
b'my'
b'name'
b'is'
b'Buddy.'
b'I'
b'am a'
b'superhero'
b'.'
b'At least,'
b'I think'
b'so...:)'
b'What'
b'do you'
b'think'
b'?'
b'Let me know. :)'
```

However, it adds a character `b` in front of each line of text.

How can I remove that?

Comment: Try removing the line `data = data.encode('ascii')`

Comment: @iota, hmm...it works. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the line

```
data = data.encode('ascii')
```

Answer (score 0):

[`xml.parsers.expat.ParserCreate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pyexpat.html#xml.parsers.expat.ParserCreate)

> `xml.parsers.expat.ParserCreate(encoding=None, namespace_separator=None)`
>
> Creates and returns a new xmlparser object. encoding, if specified, must be a string naming the encoding used by the XML data. Expat doesn’t support as many encodings as Python does, and its repertoire of encodings can’t be extended; it supports UTF-8, UTF->16, ISO-8859-1 (Latin1), and ASCII.

You can just pass the encoding to your `ParserCreate` function inside `Parse` method.

`xmlParser = expat.ParserCreate(encoding='ASCII')`